# \usepackage{SIunits} error \square already defined

Tags: errors, siunits

Has anyone else encountered the error:

```
Package SIunits error: the command \square was already defined at line
\begin{document}
```

in compiling a `beamer` presentation? Is this way of using packages incorrect? I have tried commenting out the packages one-by-one to see which other packages that I have used contain `\square` but I cannot find the problem. Prior to `\usepackage{SIunits}` My document contains MWC and I still have the problem. I am using Latexian 1.2.4, Mac OS X 10.8.5.

```
\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
\title{Title}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{SIunits}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SIunits` has to be loaded with certain options to avoid this. But there is a better solution, drop `SIunits` altogether and use `siunitx` instead.

Comment: The option is `squaren`: `\usepackage[squaren]{SIunits}`; but I agree that loading `siunitx` is way better.